# Evaluating the magnitude. Is this less than 1?

Tags: real-analysis

Where $|x|<1$, I'm looking to determine if

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}(-1+\sqrt{1-x^2})\right|<1$$

I believe it is, since we can use a Taylor series to approximate

$$\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{4}(x^2)^2 + O(3) \approx 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2$$

This then gives

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}(-1+\sqrt{1-x^2})\right| \approx \left|\frac{1}{x}(-1+1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2)\right| = \left|-\frac{x}{2}\right|<1$$

This, though, is not a proof. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$
\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}{x}\right| = \left|-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1} \right| \leq \frac{|x|}{1}=|x|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $2y=\arcsin x,0\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies x=\sin2y,\cos2y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}x=\dfrac{\cos2y-1}{\sin2y}=\cdots=-\tan y$$

Now $$0\le y\le\dfrac\pi4\implies0\le\tan y\le1$$

Comment: For $y \in [0,\pi/4]$, $\tan y \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood, Thanks for your observation